# Any closed subset of $\mathbb C$ is the set of limit points of some sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

> Let $X$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb C$ with the usual norm.
>
> Prove that there exists some complex sequence $(u_n)$ such that $X$ is **exactly** the set of limit points of $(u_n)$.

For the sake of clarity, let me re-define the set of limit points of a sequence.

> $l$ is a limit point of $(u_n)$ iff there a subsequence of $(u_n)$ that converges to $l$.
>
> Equivalenty,  $l$ is a limit point of $(u_n)$ iff for every neighbourhood $V$ of $l$, there are infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $u_n ∈ V$.

I proved the converse of the assertion above, and I'm stuck with the direct implication. I can't build such $(u_n)$ with my bare hands, and I tried contradiction, without success.

Comment: Maybe you can build such a sequence using an enumeration of $X \cap \mathbb Q + i\mathbb Q$, not sure though.

Comment: @Alex What if $X = \mathbb{R} + \sqrt{2}i$?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yeah, thought it wouldn't be that easy, though given this _specific_ set you can of course take an enumeration of $\mathbb Q + \sqrt2 i$... Looks like one may be able to generalise that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subspaces of separable normed spaces](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180708/subspaces-of-separable-normed-spaces)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Though quite relevant, I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi could you elaborate on how this is a duplicate ?

Comment: @G.T.R Though I don't think it's a duplicate, if you take $X$ to be the subspace the question says that $X$ is seperable so it has a countable dense subset, wich you can enumerate for your sequence $u_m$

Comment: Very similar to [Given closed $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ find a sequence with subsequences convergent to every point in $C$ and nowhere else](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74632/given-closed-c-subseteq-mathbbr-find-a-sequence-with-subsequences-converge).

Comment: For a more interesting result, prove that such a sequence can always be chosen so that for each point in the closed set, there exists a subsequence convering to that point whose indices have [upper asymptotic density $1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A subspace of a normed space is separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180708/subspaces-of-separable-normed-spaces), hence $X$ is separable. Let $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a countable dense subset.

Now $X$ has a countable number of isolated points (if $x \in X$ is isolated, pick a ball around $x$ not intersecting $X$, then this ball contains a point of $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ and hence we get an injection $\{\text{isolated points}\} \to \mathbb{Q}[i]$ and this last set is countable). Let $I = \{y_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ be the set of isolated points (maybe there are repetitions, it's not a problem).

Form the sequence $y_{n,m}$ by setting:
$$y_{n,m} = \begin{cases}
x_n & m = 0 \\
y_m & m > 0
\end{cases}$$
And let $z_k = y_{f(k)}$ where $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}^*$ is a bijection.

This sequence meets any isolated point of $X$ an infinite number of times by design, so that isolated point will be a limit point of $z_k$.

If $x \in X$ is not an isolated point, let $V$ be a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$; then $V$ is infinite. Since the initial sequence $\{x_n\}$ was dense in $X$, it's also dense in $V \cap X$, but this set is infinite (because $x$ isn't an isolated point of $X$), and so $\{z_k\} \cap V \cap X$ will be infinite too (because a finite subset wouldn't be dense in an infinite one, because $\mathbb{C}$ is a metric space).

And any limit point of $\{z_k\} \subset X$ lies in $\bar X = X$. This concludes.

Comment: Close, but you need to treat isolated points of $X$ specially.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I don't understand why $X$ has to be separable. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @G.T.R $\mathbb{C}$ is separable ($\mathbb{Q}[i]$ is dense), now use the answer I linked.

Comment: @Daniel I updated my answer (you were right, there was some work to do; I don't believe it's a duplicate anymore).

Comment: I think you meant $I = \{y_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}^*}$

Comment: @G.T.R Good catch.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It took me time to understand the gist of your proof, but I concur. Great answer.

Comment: @Stefan Yes, of course.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I added a simpler proof.

Answer (score 2):

For a sequence $(a_n)$ the set of its limit points is

$$\cap_{n\ge 1} \overline{\{a_n, a_{n+1}, \ldots \}}$$

From  a sequence $(r_n)$  construct the sequence

$$r_1,\  r_1, r_2,\  r_1, r_2 ,r_3,\  \ldots,\  r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_n, \ldots $$

with the set of limit points $\overline{\{r_1, r_2, \ldots \}}$

Obs: Works in general topological spaces.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding. How does this address the question?

Comment: @Andres Caicedo: Perhaps $(r_{n})$ is intended to be a sequence of elements in the closed set that is dense in the closed set?

Comment: Hi @Dave. Perhaps. It seems puzzling that the existence of such a sequence is treated as a blackbox, while the small detail of how to ensure that such a sequence works is elaborated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler approach.

To prove the wanted result, it suffices to build a sequence $(v_n)\in X^{\mathbb N}$ such that, $$\forall \lambda \in X, \forall \epsilon>0, \forall N \in \mathbb N, \exists n_0 \geq N, |v_{n_0}-\lambda|\leq \epsilon$$

---

Since $\mathbb C$ is separable, there exists a dense, countable subset $D$ of $\mathbb C$.

Let's define $(u_n)$ such that $D=\{u_n | n \in \mathbb N\}$.

Since $X$ is closed, for each $n\in \mathbb N$, one can define the projection $v_n$ of $u_n$ on $X$, that is $v_n \in \{ x\in X \;\;|\;\;|u_n-x|\; \text{is minimal }\}$.

---

It remains to prove that $(v_n)$ meets our requirements.

Let $\epsilon >0$ and $N\in \mathbb N$.

Let $\displaystyle A=\{n\in \mathbb N \;| \;\; |u_n-\lambda|\leq \frac{\epsilon}3\}$.

It's easy to check that $A$ is infinite.

Moreover, if $n\in A$, then $|v_n- \lambda|\leq \epsilon$

Otherwise, $$\epsilon \leq |v_n-\lambda|\leq |v_n-u_n|+|u_n-\lambda|\leq |\lambda-u_n|+|u_n-\lambda|\leq\frac{2\epsilon}3$$

Since $A$ is infinite, choose any $n_0 \in A$ with $n_0 \geq N$. We have$|v_{n_0}-\lambda|\leq \epsilon$

---

**PS**: One sees that the result still holds if $\mathbb C$ is replaced with any separable metric space that has Bolzano-Weierstrass property.