# Subspace of a separable space is separable

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a separable space and $Y \subset X$. Show that $(Y,d)$ is also separable.

My approach is as follows:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a separable space and $Y \subset X$. Since $X$ is separable, by definition there exists a countable dense subset in $X$, call it $K$. We want to show that $K \subset Y$.

Is this a valid approach to take to the proof?

P.S. This is an analysis course, not strictly a topology course.

Answer (score 11):

You need to construct a completely new dense subset for $Y$ as $Y$ may in fact completely "avoid" your given dense set.
One should pick points in $Y$ that are near the given ones, and the notion of nearness should strengthened.
So let $Q=\{q_1,q_2,\ldots\}$ be a countable subset of $X$ that is dense in $X$.
Then the open balls $B(q_n,\frac 1m)$, $(n,m)\in\Bbb N^2$, form a basis of the topology of $X$, i.e., any open set $U$ is the union of some $B(q_n,\frac 1m)$.
For every $(n,m)$ with $B(q_n,\frac1m)\cap Y\ne\emptyset$, pick a point $p_{n,m}\in B(q_n,\frac1m)\cap Y$. Then the set of all $p_{n,m}$ is countable.
It is also dense: Any relatively open subset $V$ of $Y$ is of the form $V=U\cap Y$ with $U$ open in $X$. This $U$ is the union of some $B(q_n,\frac 1m)$, and at least one of these must intersect $Y$. The corresponding point $p_{n,m}$ is then $\in V$.

Comment: That escalated quickly.

Comment: do you know the $B(q_n,\frac{1}{m})$ intersect $Y$ nontrivially as they form a base for the topology on $X$? and $Y \subset X$?

Answer (score 2):

This won't quite work.  What you need to do is look at $K\cap Y$.  You need to show that $K\cap Y$ is countable and dense in $Y$.

Comment: It won't be. Think of $X=\Bbb R$, $K=\Bbb Q$, $Y=\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$

Comment: Good point. It should be noted that $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ is still separable, just that $K\cap Y$ is not the countable dense set needed.

Comment: Thanks for these remarks. Is there a better way to proceed?