# Show that $L^1_\mathcal{F}$ is separable

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, separable-spaces

Let $(\Omega, P)$ be a separable, perfect probability space. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a closed $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$. Let $L^1_\mathcal{F}$ be the subspace of $L^1(\Omega)$ consisting of all the $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variables. Show that $L^1_\mathcal{F}$ is a separable space.

I know that $L^1(\Omega)$ is separable since $(\Omega, P)$ is strongly isomorphic to $(S, \mu)$ for some $S \subset \mathbb{R}^1$ and some $K$-regular probability measure $\mu$. We can take
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^n a_i 1_{[\alpha_i, \beta_i)}
$$
for $a_i, \alpha_i, \beta_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ on $L^1(S)$. I wonder how we can apply this idea for $L^1_\mathcal{F}$, or if there is any other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, $L_\mathcal{F}^1$ is a subspace of $L^1$. Therefore, we can use the following fact.

[Subspace of a separable space is separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628253/subspace-of-a-separable-space-is-separable)

Comment: Note: In a general topological space, the second-countableness, that there exists a countable open basis, implies the separableness. In a metric space, the separableness implies the second-countableness as we think of $\{ B(a_n, 1/m) \}$. We take a countable open basis $\mathcal{U} \subset L^1$ and set $\mathcal{U}' = \{ U \cap L^1_\mathcal{F} \mid U \in \mathcal{U} \}$. We see that $\mathcal{U}'$ is a countable open basis.