# Show that a subset $Y$ of metric space $X$ is separable if there exists a sequence of points in $X$ whose closure contains $Y$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I'm trying to show that a subset $Y$ of metric space $X$ is separable if there exists a sequence of points in $X$ whose closure contains $Y$.

Attempt: I know that separable means that $Y$ must contain a countable dense subset. If we denote the sequence $\{x_n\}$ then it would seem that its closure should also be $\{x_n\}$, and potentially any limit point of $\{x_n\}$ in case the sequence converges, considering we may think of $\{x_n\}$ as the union of singelton sets $x_1\cup x_2 \cup x_3 \cup ...$ and each singleton set has an open complement (as derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459067/are-singletons-always-closed)) and thus the union of all the complements will be open and therefore the sequence is closed. Since the closure is the smallest closed set containing $\{x_n\}$ the closure would be $\{x_n\}$. But I would think that I somehow missunderstand what the closure of $\{x_n\}$ constitutes and therefore I'm unable to make progress.

Comment: This is trivially true. The sequence is a countable dense set of $Y$.

Comment: @Simplyorange No it's not.  The sequence doesn't have to live in $Y$.

Comment: Remember that the rationals are countable and dense in $\Bbb R$.  There are many enumerations of the rationals, but none of them converge.  Nevertheless, all of these enumerations have uncountably many limit points.  That's because the rationals (however they're enumerated) have uncountably many convergent subsequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Fact**: every subspace of a separable metrizable space is separable (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628253/subspace-of-a-separable-space-is-separable)).

Let $C$ be the closure of a sequence in $X$ and assume that $Y\subset C$. Since $C$ is the closure of a countable set, it is separable. Then, $Y$ is separable, being a subset of $C$.

**Note**: metrizability is necessary for the fact to hold. Counterexample: the anti-diagonal in the Sorgenfrey plane is a non-separable subspace of a separable space.